# Como adicionar o valor de um id_UsuarioLogado para um FK?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá…

Bom, supondo que um usuário quer fazer um comentário em uma postagem qualquer. O sistema deve:

1. Verificar se o usuário está logado, senão ele receberá um script
   “você deve estar logado para comentar”.
2. Se o usuário estiver logado, então deve pegar o id desse usuário e passar para `autor_coment` (que é uma `FK` da tabela comentários)

É isso. Como estou iniciando e não achei nenhum exemplo de códigos como esse, resolvi pedir ajuda aqui. Porém, quando cadastro o comentário não posso deixar `autor_coment` nulo, já que é uma `FK`. Então, queria pegar o id do usuário logado e passar para `autor_coment`.

Resumindo... quando eu cadastrar um comentário eu não posso deixar essa a `FK` `autor_coment` nula. Então, quero passar o valor do id do usuário logado pra essa `FK`.

Até então, tenho esse código para cadastrar os comentários:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['comentar'])){
            $autor_coment       = trim(strip_tags($_POST['autor_coment']));
            $comentario             = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comentario']));

    if(empty($autor_coment)){
        echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para comentar.'); history.back();</script>";
    }elseif(empty($comentario)){
        echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para comentar.'); history.back();</script>";
    }else{

    $insert = "INSERT into comentarios (autor_coment, comentario) VALUES (:autor_coment, :comentario)";

        try{
            $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':autor_coment', $autor_coment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->bindParam(':comentario', $comentario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();
            if($contar>0){
                echo "<script>alert('Seu comentário foi enviado com sucesso!')</script>";
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Erro! Não foi possível comentar')</script>";
            }           
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }   
    }
}
?>

<br>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <p>

                        <input 
                        style="width: 400px;" 
                        type="" 
                        name="id"

                        required
                        placeholder="ID">

                        <br><br>

                        <input 
                        style="width: 400px; height: 150px;"
                        type="text" 
                        id="comentario" 
                        name="comentario" 
                        value="" 
                        required
                        placeholder="Digite seu comentário"
                        /> 

<br>
                    <a style="padding-left: 280px;">
                        <input 
                        style="width:120px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;"
                        type="submit" 
                        name="comentar" 
                        class="w3-button w3-black w3-section"
                        value="Comentar"
                        />
                    </p></a>

    </form>
```

Estou pegando o ID do usuário no comentário e não estou verificando se o usuário está ou não logado. Portanto, são dois problemas que não faço ideia de como resolver.

Comment: Você já faz a autenticação do usuário?

Comment: Sim, a autenticação do usuário já foi feita.

Comment: Então, você deve ter o ID do usuário registrado na sessão e é este valor que você usará na variável `$autor_coment`. Ao mesmo tempo exiba a parte de comentários se o usuário estiver autenticado, caso contrário escreva o "você precisa estar logado para comentar".

Comment: Ok, vou tentar isso. Obrigado!